# System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, imagesource

Hello I do have a Problem quite a lot of people seem to have but i tried the suggested Solutions and they haven't worked. I have this Code that always throws a exception (Message: "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception") at the Window.InitializeComponent() Methode.
Here is My Xaml Code:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMoving.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Name="SquareFighter" Height="392" Width="621" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" KeyUp="Window_KeyUp" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas">
        <Rectangle Name="Box" Height="60" Canvas.Left="17" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="172" Width="30">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Peanut.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Name="Rec1" Height="30" Canvas.Left="908" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="50" Width="30">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Rock.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Height="30" Canvas.Left="908" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="110" Width="30">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Rock.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Height="30" Canvas.Left="908" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="169" Width="30">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Rock.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Height="30" Canvas.Left="908" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="229" Width="30">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Rock.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Height="30" Canvas.Left="908" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="289" Width="30">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Rock.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Label Name="LevelLabel" Content="Level: 1" Canvas.Left="54" Canvas.Top="10" Height="38" Width="164" FontSize="20"/>
        <Label Content="Shoot the squares back using WSDA!" Canvas.Left="180" Width="290" FontSize="16"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I don't know what to do. I hope you can help.

Comment: The problem is in your code-behind, the XAML looks fine.

Comment: But the Problem accrued as I stated using the ImageBushes

Comment: I dont adjusted the images in my code could the Resource-file have a problem?

Comment: @Tifferan - Have you make sure both the points in my answer holds valid for your images?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you don't have images located under Resources folder.

Make sure following things holds valid for both images *(Rock.png and Peanut.png)* used in your XAML:

1. Image is **`added in project under Resources folder`** in same project.
2. **`Build Action`** for image is set to **`Resource`**.

---

Also, you can try using more verbose Pack URI definition:

`"pack://application:,,,/SimpleMoving;component/Resources/Peanut.png"` and `"pack://application:,,,/SimpleMoving;component/Resources/Rock.png"` where SimpleMoving is name of your assembly.

Comment: I do have them in the Resources folder but where do i set the build action?

Comment: Right click on image and select properties. You will see build Action there, change it to Resource if not already.

Comment: Have you set Resource for both images? And your window and resource folder are in same project or different?

Comment: Ok, i will update the answer with this. Also accept the answer if it works for you - [How to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).